# Configure maven-surefire-report-plugin to read from multiple source directories

Tags: java, maven, maven-surefire-plugin

I have configured surefire to use different output directories based on CPU count:

```xml
<plugin>
   <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
   <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
   <configuration>
       <forkCount>3C</forkCount>
       <reportsDirectory>target/surefire-reports-${surefire.forkNumber}</reportsDirectory>
   </configuration>
</plugin>
```

I can see directories `target/surefire-reports-[1..36]` (could be more or less depending on machine build runs). How can I make the report plugin pick up the data from there?
I tried:

```xml
<plugin>
   <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
   <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>3.0.0-M7</version>
   <configuration>
       <reportsDirectories>
           <reportsDirectory>target/surefire-reports*</reportsDirectory>
       </reportsDirectories>
   </configuration>
</plugin>
```

But nothing was picked up.

Comment: Looking at this pretty quickly doesn't seem like (wildcard) works.  Can you look into maven exec plugin or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17963222/assign-output-of-exec-maven-plugin-to-variable to define a variable of the folder that exists on the machine you run on by looking at the directory contents?

Or your other option is to list all `target/surefire_reports_1`, etc till 36 under `reportDirectories`

Comment: Thx for the quick reply. Tried the 36 dirs too. Didn’t seem to work

Comment: Can you explain the reason why needed different output for difference cpu count?

Comment: @stwissel what do you mean with 36 dirs, it is not working? Are you getting filenotfound or?  Please show an update of what you tried.